# thumbnail_width not working in wordpress most popular post plugin

Tags: plugins, shortcode, blog-page, bug

I have been using WordPress most popular plugin to get popular post using short code. By default the plugin generated the feature image by 100x75. I want that in 200x200.
I use this query to get the thumbnail as I want but it's not working.

```
if ( function_exists('wpp_get_mostpopular') ) {
    $pop_posts = wpp_get_mostpopular(array(
        'limit' => 8,
        'range' => 'all',
        'excerpt_length' => 25,
        'excerpt_by_words' => 1,
        'thumbnail_width' => 200,
        'thumbnail_height' => 200,
        'post_html' => '<li class="feature-blog-card flex flex-col">{thumb_img} <a href={url}><div class="top-part"><h3 class="wpp-title">{text_title}</h3></div></a></li>',
        'thumbnail_width' => 100,
        'thumbnail_height' => 75,
        'order_by' => 'views'
    ));
    print_r($pop_posts);
}
```

Comment: Your best bet to get this solved would be to inquire with the plugin developer - their plugin may be doing something different.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.